# FaceBook fan-block in a text-widget

Tags: facebook

I want to add a facebook-fanbox on a wordpress-page. I can go about this in the following matter:

I take the test from the [facebook-developer site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages).

Initialize the JavaScript SDK using this app: books-page...

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div> <script>(function(d, s, id) {   var js, fjs =
 d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;   js
 = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=473241986032774&version=v2.0";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script',
 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening `<body>` tag.

Or do I need to include this?

```
 <div class="fb-like-box"
 data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" 
 data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true"
 data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

Which text has to be added into a text-block widget? Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to include both pieces of code in the text widget like this. BTW, When you pasted your code, you missed a `>` in `</script>`. I fixed it in my edit and answer

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> <script>(function(d, s, id) {   var js, fjs =
 d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;   js
 = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=473241986032774&version=v2.0";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script',
 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like-box"
 data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" 
 data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true"
 data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help :-)